# I have a column with 1000 rows. It has names of 10 countries. How can i know how many times each country is repeated?

Tags: r, count

I have a column with 1000 rows. It has names of 10 countries. How can i count how many times each country is repeated?

Comment: Have a look at `?table`. However, this is a very basic task in R, and so a bit more research might very well have turned up the answer you're looking for.

Comment: p.s. the downvote wasn't from me!

Answer (score 7):

The most specific solution is to use `table`.

```
table(my.column)
```

`summary` does different things depending on data type, but `table` always show the number of occurrances for every unique value. If you would code countries with ID numbers instead of character strings for instance, `summary` would show quartiles which is not what you want.

Answer (score 1):

You can use summary(name_of_data_frame) function. Example:

```
fff<-c("d1","d1","d2")
f1<-data.frame(fff)
summary(f1)
```

The result:
 fff
 d1:2
 d2:1

Answer (score 1):

If your countries names are entered as factors you can use directly `summary(my_data)`, otherwise `summary(as.factor(my_data))`. For instance:

```
my_data <- sample(LETTERS[1:10], 1000, replace=TRUE)
summary(as.factor(my_data))
  A   B   C   D   E   F   G   H   I   J 
 99 111 106  89  90  90 109 105  96 105
```