# Extracting values from vectors in R

Tags: r

I have a vector with loads of entries (380). I'd like to plot a graph of the values, but to do that I need to extract the frequencies of each value. For instance, in a vector (1,2,2,3,4) the numbers 1, 3 and 4 crop up once, and the number 2 twice. What should I do to obtain this info?

Comment: This is a really basic question, incidentally. I would think that a quick Google search of "frequencies in R" would have answered your question.

Comment: this was basically just asked 5 hours ago http://stackoverflow.com/q/12300470/1317221

Answer (score 3):

The function `table` is your friend:

```
plot(table(myvector))
```

Answer (score 1):

Note that, if you want to handle the output and do further operations, you can enclose it with as.data.frame to get a dataframe.

```
df <- as.data.frame(table(myvector))
```

**EDITED TO ADD**
Right, you have to create a new object to do operations on it, as the comment below says.

Comment: note: you will need to name it obviously `df<-as.data.frame(table(myvector))` if you want to perform further operations